# Save html value of all text fields as a Ruby array using Sinatra

Tags: html, ruby, post, text, sinatra

I am creating a webapp that outputs a table and empty columns. The user enters information into the columns then I want to save those entries and re display the entire table including the information the user entered. How can I save all entries in the text field once the user hits submit? The cells are created using a loop so the same variable will be used over and over again.

I tried searching through stack overflow and google and couldn't figure out the answer to my problem. I'm new to sinatra.

```
<% events.each do |event| %>
  <% row_of_data = [ ] %>
  <tr>
  <% event = event.first(14) %>
  <% event.each do |key, value| %>
    <% row_of_data << value %>
    <td>
    <%= value %>
    </td>
  <% end %>
    <td><input type="text" name="event_description"></td>
    <% row_of_data << params["event_description"] %>
    <td><input type="text" name="event_type">
    <% row_of_data << params['event_type'] %>
    <td><input type="text" name="event_class">
    <% row_of_data << params['event_class'] %>
    <td><input type="text" name="issue_expert"></td>
    <% row_of_data << params['issue_expert'] %>
  </tr>
```

row_of_data is getting null values for everything that is is in the html text box's. I understand why this is happening because this is running in the GET method and therefore when it is saving this data it's before the user has entered data. How can I get the values inside of all the html boxes after the user has entered into the boxes so I can use those values in my POST method?

Comment: Is it a editable html table or a table with forms in it? Can you show the table html and Sinatra table generator code please?

Comment: How is it submitted?

Comment: I'm going to delete this post. this one is outdated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171182/save-all-user-entries-from-html-text-built-off-a-loop-using-ruby-and-sinatra.